# How to calculate the recipe ingredient counter in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to calculate the quantity of the ingredients by the serve count. But, the counter i have implemented is not supporting fraction values such as 3/4 teaspoon, 2 1/2 teaspoon. Here is the sample code:

```
  var gcd = function(a, b) {
    if (b < 0.0000001) return a;                
    return gcd(b, Math.floor(a % b));   
  };
  
  const decimalToFraction = ( ) => {
    var fraction = result;
    var len = fraction.toString().length - 2;
    var denominator = Math.pow(10, len);
    var numerator = fraction * denominator;
    var divisor = gcd(numerator, denominator);  
    numerator /= divisor;                       
    denominator /= divisor;                   
    console.log(Math.floor(numerator) + '/' + Math.floor(denominator));
  }
  const stringToDecimal = (parseQuantity) => {
    let split = parseQuantity.split('/');
    let result = parseInt(split[0], 10) / parseInt(split[1], 10);
    return result;
  }
  const serveQuantity = (count) =>{
    let listOfIngredients=[];
      if(count<1 && serve >= 1){
          setServe(serve => serve-1);
          listOfIngredients =ingredients.map((item,index)=>{
                  if(quantity[index] < 1){
                    item.quantity._text = item.quantity._text - parseInt(quantity[index]);
                  }else{
                    item.quantity._text = parseInt(item.quantity._text) - parseInt(quantity[index]);
                  }
                  return item;
          })
      }
      
      if(count===1 && serve >= 1){
          setServe(serve => serve+1);
          listOfIngredients = ingredients.map((item, index)=>{
            if(quantity[index] < 1){
              item.quantity._text = item.quantity._text + parseInt(quantity[index]);
            }else{
              item.quantity._text = parseInt(item.quantity._text) + parseInt(quantity[index]);
            }
              return item;
          })
      }
      setIngredients(listOfIngredients);
  }
```

when the user clicks on the serve `+/-` button, i'm calling `serveQuantity(2)` function.

Comment: why you don't keeep all values in floats, manipualte in floats and only display it in fractions? just last step transforming value from float to farction in displaying component. isn't this be just simpler ?

Comment: yeah, this was my initial approach. the function i have implemented is not supported mixed fraction for instance: 3 3/4. Any idea to retain the mixed fraction.

Comment: if you want to parse the string "3 3/4" to a float you have to use the split function using space as delimeter then you get the interger part as first element and the fractional part as second element, so you can parse then into floats

Comment: you can use something like this [lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/num2fraction)  i believe that mathjs have some of that functionality as well.